# Use of conjunctive adverb with participle clause

Tags: participles

I have written a sentence by using participle clause

any contribution cannot be erased from the mind, therefore being essential for being successful.

But my teacher is saying that "therefore being essential for being successful" is not correct.

But I have read that I can connect two sentences together having same subjects.

In this case 1. any contribution cannot be erased from the mind 2. Therefore, any contribution is essential for being successful" is not correct.

So to me, my sentence was correct since two sentences had same subjects. I suppose, using conjunctive adverb like therefore, hence, thus with participle clause can be a reason for him to mark this incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: In the phrase *"being essential for being successful"*, do the two verbs *being* have the same subject? I don't see how the sentence makes sense if they do. And if they don't, you really shouldn't omit both of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of cases when you can connect together two sentences having the same subject and even if this were one of them, that wouldn’t be the right method.

*… being essential for being successful…* should be *… being essential for success…*

Quite separately, either *any contribution can…* or *no contribution cannot…* and even that should really be *there is no contribution which cannot…*